# Flutter : how to change text data by bottomSheet?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to change my text, after selecting by bottomsheet text is not changing when i am refreshing then my text is changing.

how to fix this issue.

This is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../Utils/GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../../../Utils/GlobalTextStyles/global_text_styles.dart';

class NonVegPizzaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NonVegPizzaPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NonVegPizzaPage> createState() => _NonVegPizzaPageState();
}

class _NonVegPizzaPageState extends State<NonVegPizzaPage> {
  String itemSize = "Regular";
  List itemSizes = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    itemSizes = [
      {
        "sizes": "Regular",
      },
      {
        "sizes": "Medium",
      },
      {
        "sizes": "Large",
      },
    ];
  }

  sizeBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
          ),
        ),
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState1) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: MyColor.whiteColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: MyColor.greyColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 0), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 43.0, top: 10, bottom: 11),
                    child: Text(
                      "Select Size",
                      style: textStyleWith14500(MyColor.blackColor2),
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: itemSizes.length,
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 0,
                          ),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              setState1(() {
                                itemSize = itemSizes[index]["sizes"];
                              });
                              print(itemSize);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
                              height: 36,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              color: itemSize == itemSizes[index]["sizes"]
                                  ? MyColor.lightBlueColor
                                  : MyColor.whiteColor,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 43.0, top: 10),
                                child: Text(
                                  "${itemSizes[index]["sizes"]}",
                                  style:
                                      textStyleWith12400(MyColor.blackColor3),
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("$itemSize"),                                // here
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  sizeBottomSheet();
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 44,
                  width: 150,
                  child: Center(child: Text("show bottomSheet")),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`showModalBottomSheet` is a future method, you can await to close it and then call setState to update the main ui.

```dart
  sizeBottomSheet() async {
    final result = await showModalBottomSheet(
    ....  
   onTap: () {
     Navigator.pop(context, itemSizes[index]["sizes"]);
    .......
//end of showModalBottomSheet
    if (result != null) {
      itemSize = result;
      setState(() {});
    }
```

Or you can do

```dart
child: InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    setState1(() {
      itemSize = itemSizes[index]["sizes"];
    });
    setState(() {});//updating the parent
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
```